# HTTP code 302 encountered when deploying a web app on Google App Engine

Tags: http, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-platform

I have a Java Servlet web application deployed to Google App Engine.

It has a login page and when the user is successfully logged in, it navigates to the Home servlet.

The http site stopped working from today's redeployment/upgrade to the app due to the code 302. And it only occurred on the computer when the redeployment/upgrade was performed.

When trying the app with the http protocol, it threw http 302 on the Home servlet. Then it navigated back the login page.

[image]

When trying with https protocol, however, it navigated correctly to the Home servlet on http 200.

[image]

Not sure if this is a GAE setting issue or a browser thing (I am with firefox)?

EDIT: I realised that the http site worked fine again if I cleared the cache on firefox. But when I accessed the https site, http stopped working again due to the same 302 issue.

Answer (score 0):

`302`s are not necessarily "failures"; They are redirects.  When a user goes to log in, are you redirecting them?  Perhaps from an `http` to an `https` login page?  And when they log in, are you redirecting them back to the original page?